# Amazon Product Advertising API Top Seller response group does not return other item attributes

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I've been using this code:

```
defined('AWS_API_KEY') or define('AWS_API_KEY', 'AGGAVZCVASDG123A');
defined('AWS_API_SECRET_KEY') or define('AWS_API_SECRET_KEY', '132131235151asdfaGFfasdf');
defined('AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG') or define('AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG', 'test05-12');
$amazonEcs = new AmazonECS(AWS_API_KEY, AWS_API_SECRET_KEY, 'com', AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->associateTag(AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->returnType(AmazonECS::RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY);

$response = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('TopSellers')->browseNodeLookup($node);
```

Unfortunately this code does not return the product's Price, Images and other attributes. 
It only returns this result:

```
<TopItemSet>
   <Type>TopSellers</Type>
   <TopItem>
            <ASIN>0553576399</ASIN>
            <Title>Distraction</Title>
            <ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
            <Author>Bruce Sterling</Author>
       </TopItem>
       <TopItem>
        ....
       .....
</TopItemSet>
```

**Is there a way I can show those when calling the `TopSellers` response group?**

I have a solution before that everytime I call `TopSellers`, I get the ASIN of the items that the TopSellers produced(they produced 10 top seller items), then I use this code:

```
$response = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('Images,ItemAttributes')->page(1)->category('All')->search($asin);
```

That would do a searching of the product that is based on the ASIN that the TopSeller response group produced. The only problem with this code is that it will cause a `throttled error`. Throttled Error means the my request limit on amazon api have exceeded, because obviously that code is kinda exhausting to call because it keeps on requesting data from API.

I've been reading the docs of Product Advertising API here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_TopSellers.html

Your thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, I would like to know how do you initialize $node

Comment: what node? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean $node in browseNodeLookup($node), where does that $node come from?

Comment: @PaulLo Basically nodes are unique identifiers of categories in amazon. Here's the guide of the node you're asking for http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html An example will be $node = '2619525011';

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now. I was confused because I thought $node is the identifier of specific product which we would not know, now I understand it's just for categories.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower Which PHP Library are you using? I am using one for Product Advertising API and could not find this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already have an answer on my own question:

It can be found here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=435522&#435522

Thanks! :)